# Build an apk file without module dependency

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies

I am developing an Android SDK, we have two modules: core and optional. Both modules are supplied as separate aar files.
Some of the core-module classes have an import of the optional-module classes. For some clients of the SDK the optional module will not be used (provided) and the classes of the core-module that import classes from the optional module will not be used during runtime.

Is there a way to build an application with the gradle that will include only the core module? Or is there any other approach?